# Problems with charset reading file. How to fix it

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8

Input to read the file `Jade`:

```
input#upload.(type='file', accept="text/xml, .csv")
```

and get in js:

```
 var file = document.getElementById('upload').files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(e){
     var file = e.target.result;
};
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

I get a line:

> "mail;name;Ð¢ÐµÑÑ"

where `Ð¢ÐµÑÑ` in the last element in the file is a russian word.

how to fix charset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symptom is clear: you are (inadvertently) splicing UTF-8 (judging by your tag) content into something that is being presented as something else (not-UTF-8), hence mojibake ensues.

Make sure that every pass the content goes through is UTF-8 clean or preserves the original content byte-for-byte exactly. That includes setting Content-type headers appropriately (Likely: `text/html; charset=utf-8`).

This precise issue is why it is recommended to use UTF-8 for **all the things**. Set up your DBs to use UTF-8, set up your webserver to serve UTF-8, set up your source code to be in UTF-8, set up your editors to save in UTF-8 by default, set up your HTTP headers and meta tags to advertise UTF-8, do not accept anything that is not UTF-8 or transcode it where feasible. Anything that is not UTF-8 is just asking for trouble.

Why standardise on UTF-8, you ask? Because it's low 7bit range happens to look like ASCII which can make a whole world of difference in interoperability with broken/legacy things that don't really understand much else.

Comment: I have a template(jade), angular script, user input file and nodejs/expressjs server. All files in UTF-8 charset.